# 2 tables with same primary id cannot equal each other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 user tables - one for employees and one for temp workers.  Both have userid as the primary key.  I would like to ensure that a new record on one does not match the userid on the other.  I can do this in my php code; but I'm wondering if there is a restraint in MySQL that will help ensure this.
Ex:
Table 1
userid - name - email - ...
bsmith - Bob Smith - ...

Table 2
userid - name - contracthouse - ...
jallen - Joe Allen - ...

If I insert a new contract employee into Table 2; is there a MySQL constraint that would keep me from entering "bsmith" (this is what I would want); or is that only achievable in the php code?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you store both employees and temp workers in the same table?

Comment: Even if you *could* do this, you probably shouldn't. This is a pretty obvious indication that something is very wrong with your design. Store them all in the one table, then have a flag to indicate what type they are.

Comment: I would add to what @AnthonyGrist says, and say that you could store everything in a single table with a flag, and then use VIEWS to create the appearence/feel of different employee tables.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I will "merge" the tables to have one 'users; table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go about this in a couple different ways. The first would be to add triggers to each table that on insert checks to see if the record being inserted exists in the other table. If it does you can throw an exception.

The second, and probably the better way to do this would be to redesign your tables. You should only have one table holding this data and you can add a column called `user_role` or something that FKs to a lookup table containing values for the role of the user: `Full Time`, `Part Time`, `Temporary`, etc...

You can have a further child table that contains extended information about the user based on their role type, or some other such data.

Comment: Thank you gmiley.  I will redesign the tables to have one table.

Comment: @SammyG . . . There are also options where you can have multiple tables without using triggers -- although a `users` table is recommended in all cases.  It is a bit tricky, but occasionally useful if the columns are very different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're correct, in a situation where columns are vastly different I would still have the common `users` table that would contain as many similar columns as possible, with child `user_info_fulltime` and `user_info_parttime` (or similar) tables to hold the differing columns. The main point is to prevent duplication of data as much as possible. In a case like this, specifically, it is likely that a `user` is a `user` is a `user` for the majority of the data and function.

Comment: @gmiley . . . Interesting.  I think the main point is to have a primary key point to a single table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, yes - data integrity is the overall goal. =)